# Looking for JS based CSS autocompletion

Tags: javascript, css, editor

I am working on an in-browser css editor. I have a syntax highlighter, but I am looking for a JS based library that will help with the formatting and provide some intellisense.

The syntax highlighter is CodeMirror, http://codemirror.net/

Any help with intellisense would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeMirror has an example (use control+space) -- http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html

[This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors#List_of_features) shows which javascript IDE's support "code suggestions"